# Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error'?

Tags: api

**Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException'** with message

'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events

**anybody can help in this error in google api?**

400 Invalid Value' in google-api-php-client/src/io/Google_REST.php:66 Stack trace: #0

its sometimes work fine ....

Answer (score 0):

This error means to say that you have passed an incorrect value for 'cx' parameter. It should be off the format: `128254313567041584913:fdas7c-asdf`